# How do you construct a symbol in clojure?

Tags: lisp, clojure, symbols

I want to construct a macro that, given a symbol `'foo`, creates a method called `foo*`.  How can I concatenate `'foo` and `'*`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
(let [s (symbol 'test)] 
  (symbol (str s "*")))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
(symbol (str 'foo "*"))
```